# JQuery: How to determine what broswer you are in?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, navigator

$.broswer has depreciated and navigator.userAgent gives you

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36

I need a simple way to find out if I am using Chrome or not, preferably not adding a plugin.

Comment: There's allready a good awnser on Stackoverflow [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect Safari, Chrome, IE, Firefox and Opera browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser)

Comment: ...how did I not see that... do i delete this?